# Xcode update not found in App Store

Tags: xcode, xcode6, mac-app-store

I downloaded the xcode from web and installed after that i cant find any update regarding xcode on App Store. How to make the app store show updates about the xcode in app store.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you manually downloaded Xcode from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/, then the App Store app isn't aware that there's an Xcode that needs to be automatically updated.  The App Store app only keeps track of store apps it downloaded and installed itself.

You need to either download Xcode from the Mac App Store directly or you need to keep watching the http://developer.apple.com/xcode page to get informed of updates.

Comment: i need to download from  appStore.is their any possibility to get updates from the appStore.

Comment: If you download Xcode from the app store, you'll be notified of an update when Apple releases an official new version (e.g. from today's current version 7.2.1 to version 7.3, soon after it's GM'd).

Comment: Though, I seem to have lost automatic update ability and I have been using the Mac App Store all along. Suddenly, now with 13.3, I have to start downloading updates manually and Mac App Store became disconnected on its own. So that happens too.

Comment: This download page is the only hope that I have. I am certainly not going to try some kind of uninstall process and re-install to try to get it hooked up again knowing that it can unhook at any time: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

Answer (score 20):

Usually even after I update the MacOS to latest it still doesn't show the Xcode update in app store when in Update section. So what worked for me was pressing the "Reload Page" button in the Store in the toolbar menu. Make sure you're in the update section and you'll suddenly see xcode with update button pop up there. See image below.[image]

Comment: Thank you! Would've spent another hour on this had it not been for you. Crazy how the app store doesn't update automatically after an OS update.

Answer (score 3):

If none of the above solutions work, make sure that your macOS version is compatible with the XCode version, you want to upgrade to.

In my case, my macOS version was 12.4 and Xcode version was 13. The upgrade option was visible for me only after upgrading macOS version >= 12.6 as Xcode version 14 is supported only from macOS 12.6 onwards